# Причина зависания сокета на send()?

Tags: c++, сокет

Приложение работает с тремя сокетами, отправляющими данные на один php-скрипт HTTP-сервера:

1. управляющий сокет - постит присутствие клиента, получает ответы с запросами на активацию/деактивацию остальных двух сокетов. Есть команды send и recv
2. сокет вебкамеры - стримит кадры с вебки по запросу. Только send
3. сокет рабочего стола - стримит скриншоты по запросу. Только send

С 1-м проблем нет вообще - если не отправил или не получил - без каких либо ожиданий пересоздаёт подключение и работает дальше. Проблема со 2-м:

```
DWORD WINAPI NetExCamera(LPVOID){
    unsigned short StreamRate = 50;
    unsigned int OperationStartTime;
    string Header = "POST " + STREAM_URI + " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + STREAM_Host + /*другие параметры*/"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\nContent-Length: ";
    CAMERA.Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (connect(CAMERA.Socket, (SOCKADDR*)(&Target), sizeof(Target)) == 0){
        cout << "Camera socket connected!\n";
    }
    while(CAMERA.Stream){
        OperationStartTime = GetTickCount();
        CameraFrameSize = WebCam->GetFrameSize();
        CameraFrameBuffer = (unsigned char *)realloc(CameraFrameBuffer, CameraFrameSize);
        compress_image_to_jpeg_file_in_memory(CameraFrameBuffer, CameraFrameSize, RES_X ,RES_Y, 3, WebCam->CaptureFrame(), CameraCompressor);
        CameraFrame = string(reinterpret_cast<char*>(CameraFrameBuffer), CameraFrameSize);
        stringstream SendBuffer;
        SendBuffer << Header << CameraFrame.size() << "\r\n\r\n" << CameraFrame;
        // Sending data...
        cout << "Sending data...\n";
        if (send(CAMERA.Socket, &SendBuffer.str()[0], SendBuffer.str().size(), 0) < 0){
            cout << "Camera socket send error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            CameraFrame = "";
            closesocket(CAMERA.Socket);
            CAMERA.Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
            if (connect(CAMERA.Socket, (SOCKADDR*)(&Target), sizeof(Target)) == 0){
                cout << "Camera socket connected!\n";
            }
        }
        cout << "Send OK!\n";
        while(OperationStartTime + StreamRate > GetTickCount()){
            if (!CAMERA.Stream){break;}
            Sleep(1);
        }
    }
    closesocket(CAMERA.Socket);
    cout << "Camera socket disconnected!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Как видно из кода, сокет работает в своём потоке, более того send вроде по умолчанию не блокирующий, но в один момент, спустя 8-11 секунд с начала передачи данных, консольный вывод замирает на строчке `cout << "Sending data...\n";`, потом секунд через 15-20 "оттаивает", естественно сервер его уже откинул (на apache KeepAliveTimeout 5), и после этой задержки уже выходит `cout << "Camera socket send error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;` с кодом ошибки WSA 10054.

Такое ощущение, что у send есть какой-то невидимый буфер, который переполняется и отправка замирает. Размеры кадров с камеры 6-10 кб. Третий сокет работает по той же схеме, только частота у него не 20 кадров в секунду, а 2 - с ним никаких зависаний не происходит.

Проблема по какой-то причине не возникает на Windows 8.1 x64 на localhost-е, а на 7-ке вот такая беда.

**В чём реально может быть причина и как это исправить?**

Comment: send по умолчанию блокирующий. Более того, он не гарантирует отправку всех данных.

Comment: Но при send на главном сокете ведь такого не происходит - если что-то не удалось отправить, он сразу реагирует, а этот виснет

Comment: Хорошо бы посмотреть на код другой стороны... Вы уверены, что по ходу дела в ответ вам ничего не шлют? Это (в отсутствии чтения у вас) могло бы объяснить возникшую ситуацию (вы не читаете, буфер (он в самом деле есть) переполняется и та сторона висит на своем send (безуспешно ожидая, пока recv с вашей стороны не разгрузит буфер)). Так оба на своих send и висят.

Comment: Вполне возможно, что скорость заливки маленькая и оно просто не успевает за 8-11 секунд залить.

Comment: @KoVadim, 200К в секунду это не очень много (хотя, если писать в какую-нибудь СУБД...)

Comment: @avp, на стороне сервера php-скрипт никакого echo не выполняет, просто делает `shmop_write file_get_contents('php://input')` в разделяемую память. Может сам апач что-то шлёт?

Comment: Да, может и апач. Можно проверить, запустив recv с этим же сокетом в другом thread

Comment: @avp - мы не знаем какой там принимающий код и сервер. Может для него и 8 кб/с - предел.

Comment: @Iceman то есть, на локалхосте проблемы нет, а на не локалхосте есть?

Comment: @KoVadim, все возможно. Тут и начинается "экпериментальное программирование"

Comment: @Iceman, когда виснет и нет, апач один и тот же? (версия, настройки и т.п.)

Comment: @KoVadim, да, когда на localhost тестировал на домашеним ПК, где win 8.1, всё слалось без тормозов, но на рабочем, где 7-ка, на том же localhost уже проблема возникает. На реальном сервере проблема всегда. Настройки апача одинаковые - пакет OpenServer последний

Comment: Вот. И мой ответ остался тот же. send - блокирующий, более того, он не гарантирует, что запишет все данные. Количество реально записанных данных возвращается, но Вы его не проверяете.. Но на локалхосте обычно буфер большой и все данные "обычно" записываются.  Нужно аккуратно писать все данные.

Comment: Ну как не проверяю количество записанных байт? В данном примере если send < 0 - переподключаемся. Но до этого было ветвление типа if send > 0 ... ; else ... - результат один поэтому я упростил

Comment: @KoVadim, тогда вообще интересно получается. ТС каждый кадр шлет новым запросом. Если в предыдущем он послал не все content-length байт, то протокол попросту собъется (кода он следующим кадром вместе с заголовком дошлет байты предыдущего, сервер вместо следующего post прочтет фигню)

Comment: А это последствия. И логично, что сервер его отключает (и это ещё хорошее поведение. А мог и упасть).

Comment: @Iceman, вообще-то попробуйте делать send в цикле, пока не перешлете (send же возвращает сколько байт он отослал) все SendBuffer.str().size() байт

Comment: @KoVadim, а Вы помните, сервер в ответ на POST должен присылать какое-то подтверждение (даже если от скрипта никаких данных нет)?

Comment: Судя по книжке, в ответ на запрос POST сервер должен отвечать. @Iceman, проверьте строки вроде `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` вам не идут?

Comment: И правда - сервер отвечает заголовками, без контента. То есть какой-то не объявленный мифический буфер переполнялся и send вис. Я добавил recv и вуаля! Поток кадров идёт ровно столько, сколько его запрашивают, без заминок. @avp, спасибо Вам за подсказку. Это всё из-за моего неполного понимания принципа сокетов. ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В ответ на каждый HTTP POST запрос, которым вы шлете кадр с камеры, сервер шлет ответ.

Эти ответы надо читать (они переполняют буфер и  http сервер, подвисая на очередном send, не в состоянии прочесть ваш очередной запрос).

Вот так обе стороны и висят, каждая на своем send.

Кроме того, возможна ситуация, когда ваш send отошлет не все данные. Поэтому его нужно выполнять в цикле, пока все `SendBuffer.str().size()` байт не будут отосланы.

Comment: Сделал `if (send(CAMERA.Socket, &SendBuffer.str()[0], SendBuffer.str().size(), 0) == SendBuffer.str().size()){
            RecvBuffer.resize(512);
            if (recv(CAMERA.Socket, &RecvBuffer[0], RecvBuffer.size(), 0) < 0){
                CAMERA.Stream = false;}
        }`. А управляющий сокет пусть уже регулирует потоки. Всё работает. Спасибо!